# When does a turnover occur in rugby league?

Tags: rugby-league

When does a turnover occur in rugby league?

I know when an offensive team is tackled for the sixth time, the defensive team becomes the offensive team, but can this happen also during an interception or by fumble covered?

I mean, when a defensive player intercepts a ball and then he is tackled, the offensive team will be his defensive team, right? The same when an offensive player drops the ball during a backward pass, and the ball is recovered by a defensive player?

Answer (score 1):

So according to the [Laws of the Game, Rugby league](https://www.rugby-league.com/governance/rules-and-regulations/laws-of-the-game), after 5 tackles a turnover will happen if

i. The team is tackled a sixth time.

ii. The team in possession commits an accidental breach for which a scrum would normally be set.

iii. A player is held up in the opponent’s in-goal.

iv. The ball is kicked into touch on the full.

In addition it goes on to say

Where an accidental breach occurs (knock-on, forward pass) and possession changes hands, the following tackle will be a zero tackle, notwithstanding that the team gaining possession may have gained a territorial advantage.